# How to read values of variables in a web page?

Tags: javascript, java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I have to web scrape a page, but this page is dynamically loaded with some value. So, when I take the source code, there are js variables and not their values. If I download this page, I see their values.
Is there a way to read these values or to download all files (including scripts) in Java program?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium library to load an HTML document and run javascript code inside the webdriver and get anything you want.